# "loading" text showing in phonegap android application in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am in the very beginning stage of an android application in phone gap/ jQuery mobile

In eclipse I created a proj and all. Working in my device.

My problem is a "loading" text is showing in my application at footer position.

When I removed the jquery-mobile.js, then its not showing "loading". My code as follows.
How to remove this "loading" or is there anything missed in my code ?

Thanks in advance .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>     
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

<a href="#"> Start </a>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using phonegap 1.0.0? Why not Cordova 2.0.0? And where is the jquerymobile.css file?

Comment: Thanks for your help .. while adding that css file, my issue solved .. One more doubt ... Is Cordova2.js will replace phone gap ? or both needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you were missing the jquery mobile css file in your code. Adding it will make your `"loading"` look better

Secondly as i see in your code that you have used `phonegap 1.0.0` which is very old. You should use the latest version of phonegap which is now called as **cordova** and the latest version number is 2.0.0 Try using that as its awesome.